# Увеличить размер Payload dgram node.js

Tags: node.js, udp, electron

Делаю приложение на Electron. Получаю данные от других ПО по udp и возникла проблема. Имеется сообщение длиной в более 250 000 byte. В dgram ограничение в 65 000 byte. Можно ли как-то обойти его не разбивая сообщение? Пробовал устанавливать setRecvBufferSize() не помогло

Comment: Отправить 4 сообщения

Comment: Хотя если у вас там IPv6, то можно глянуть на https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2675

Comment: К сожалению нет

Comment: Тогда никак. Под размер в UDP пакете выделено 2 байта, так что больше чем 65535 туда в принципе нельзя записать